# Permutação de palavras

Tags: google-play

O intuito é criar "palavras-chave" usando algumas palavras. Por exemplo, a partir de "ideia" "título" "teste" gostaria que como saída resultasse nas possibilidades de combinação: ideiatituloteste tituloideiateste testeideiatitulo testetituloideia . . .

Atualmente uso o Crunch, mas com ele só consigo criar a combinação de letras, não de palavras, mesmo passando o parâmetro -p que segundo a documentação faria essa tarefa, pelo que entendi.

Algum site ou ferramenta (preferencialmente mobile) para tal tarefa?